# Adding an openwrap reference

Tags: openrasta, openwrap

I feel like this is a stupid question, but I'm following the tutorial for OpenWrap found here: http://codebetter.com/sebastienlambla/2010/10/20/creating-a-new-project-with-openwrap/

In the Writing Some Code section, it says to run the command:
o add-wrap log4net

I did that (but with OpenRasta-devtools instead of log4net).

It then says the project should just build.  Mine still doesn't.  There are no references to OpenRasta or OpenWrap in my solution.  Do I need to manually add this to the solution?

Seems like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenWrap adds the references at build time. You can see them in your build output being added.

Comment: I must have messed up the steps, because it didn't work on that project, but it worked on all my others.